# Compiler behaviour regarding NaN and +/- Infinity

Tags: c, nan, ieee-754

To avoid the need to link libmath I wrote the two functions I needed myself. Not that big of a problem but it's in the details where the devil lures: now I have the problem that I need to define and test for NaN and +/-Infinity without bit-juggling (cannot set the bits directly, needs to be *completly* endian-agnostic). Also not that big of a problem because all of the modern compilers support IEEE-754, or do they not? They do not. Of course, they do not. At least not in a consistent and testable way. And if they do you can switch it off. Sometimes they define a Macro, sometimes not, sometimes I don't know and here is where my rant ends and my question begins:

What compilers do support the methods of constructing and testing of NaN and 
+/-Infinity in the way listed below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef FALSEONLY
#   define PUTS(x)      // noop
#else
#   define PUTS(x) puts(x)
#endif

#define DOUBLE_MAX 1.7976931348623158e308

int main()
{
  double positive_infinity, negative_infinity, nan;
  int num_errors;

/*
 * Some compilers need that workaround.
 * 
 * Known for such behaviour are Sun C 5.0,  Compaq (formerly DEC) 6.4 and MSVC 9
 * https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2007-03/msg00360.html
 * https://github.com/rofl0r/gnulib/blob/master/tests/nan.h
 * 
 * There are compilers which do not know a NaN like the
 * C2000 CLA C Compiler (Texas Instruments). But I have older data only (from 2013),
 * that behaviour might have changed in the meantime.
 * https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest/issues/132
 */
// #if defined __SUNPRO_C ||  defined __DECC || defined _MSC_VER
#ifdef USE_ZERO
  double zero;
  zero = 0.0;
  positive_infinity = 1.0 / zero;
  negative_infinity = -1.0 / zero;
  nan = zero / zero;
#else
  /*
   * "For division, when the divisor is zero and the dividend is a finite
   * non-zero number, the sign of the infinity is the exclusive OR of
   * the operands’ signs"
   * 
   *    -- IEEE-754 2008 7.3 Division by zero
   */
  positive_infinity = 1.0 / 0.0;
  negative_infinity = -1.0 / 0.0;
  /*
   * "For operations producing results in floating-point format, the default
   * result of an operation that signals the invalid operation exception
   * shall be a quiet NaN that should provide some diagnostic information (see 6.2).
   * These operations are:
   *    [...]
   *    e) division: division(0, 0) or division(∞, ∞)
   *    [...]"
   * 
   *    -- IEEE-754 2008 7.2(e) Invalid operation
   */
  nan = 0.0 / 0.0;
#endif

  num_errors = 0;
  /*
   * " Every NaN shall compare unordered with everything, including itself."
   * 
   *    -- IEEE-754 2008 5.11 Details of comparison predicates
   * 
   * 
   * Does not work with  MSVC and GCC if the option to do "fast math" is
   * switched on.
   * 
   * GCC defines __FAST_MATH__ in that case.
   * 
   * How to check for it with MSVC?
   * 
   * What's with Intel compilers? The author doesn't have seven hundred bucks to burn
   * and cannot sign the license agreement for the "free" version with a clear conscience.
   * 
   * At least icpc 12.1.4 seems to work.
   * http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Extreme_floating_point_values#C
   */
  if (nan != nan) {
    PUTS("TRUE: nan != nan");
  } else {
    num_errors++;
    puts("FALSE: nan != nan");
  }
#ifdef USE_ZERO
  if (nan == 0.0 / zero) {
    num_errors++;
    PUTS("TRUE: nan == 0.0/0.0 (WRONG acc. to IEEE-754)");
  } else {
    puts("FALSE: nan == 0.0/0.0 (CORRECT acc. to IEEE-754)");
  }
#else
  if (nan == 0.0 / 0.0) {
    num_errors++;
    PUTS("TRUE: nan == 0.0/0.0 (WRONG acc. to IEEE-754)");
  } else {
    puts("FALSE: nan == 0.0/0.0 (CORRECT acc. to IEEE-754)");
  }
#endif
  /*
   * Outcome depends on rounding mode, see "IEEE-754 2008 7.4 Overflow" for details.
   * Must both hold if the rounding mode is either roundTiesToEven or roundTiesToAway.
   */
  if (positive_infinity == 2 * DOUBLE_MAX) {
    PUTS("TRUE: positive_infinity == 2 * DOUBLE_MAX");
  } else {
    num_errors++;
    puts("FALSE: positive_infinity == 2 * DOUBLE_MAX");
  }
  if (negative_infinity == -(2 * DOUBLE_MAX)) {
    PUTS("TRUE: negative_infinity == -(2 * DOUBLE_MAX)");
  } else {
    num_errors++;
    puts("FALSE: negative_infinity == -(2 * DOUBLE_MAX)");
  }
  /*
   * "Infinities shall be interpreted in the affine sense, that is:
   * −∞ < {every finite number} < +∞"
   * 
   *    -- IEEE-754 2008 6.1 Infinity arithmetic
   */
  if (negative_infinity < positive_infinity) {
    PUTS("TRUE: negative_infinity < positive_infinity");
  } else {
    num_errors++;
    puts("FALSE: negative_infinity < positive_infinity");
  }
  if (negative_infinity < 0) {
    PUTS("TRUE: negative_infinity < 0");
  } else {
    num_errors++;
    puts("FALSE: negative_infinity < 0");
  }
  if (positive_infinity > 0) {
    PUTS("TRUE: positive_infinity > 0");
  } else {
    num_errors++;
    puts("FALSE: positive_infinity > 0");
  }

  if (num_errors != 0) {
    printf("%d test%s failed\n", num_errors, (num_errors == 1) ? "" : "s");
  } else {
    puts("ALL OK.");
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If some compilers fail those tests (known exceptions are listed in the comments in the code above), what are these compilers and is it possible to do it in a different way?.

I have already tested, none with a problem (options for all: `-W -Wall -O3`):

- gcc-4.6.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-6ubuntu2) 4.6.4
- gcc-4.8.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
- Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
- tcc version 0.9.25

All GCCs fail the first test `nan != nan` with the option `-ffast-math` but that is documented behaviour and GCC defines a macro if that option was set, so no problem. MSVC shows the same behaviour with `/fp:fast` and it is documented, too, but I could not find an easy way to detect it, is there one?

Comment: This seems like a tremendous amount of work just to avoid linking a standard library.  One of the points of the standard math library is to provide implementations of just these kinds of things, so that you *don't* need to figure out and account for all the implementation details yourself.

Comment: In any case, "what compilers do this?" and "what compilers do not do that?" are not suitable questions for SO, as there is no way to write a definitive answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's why I added the last sentence, the question about MSVC. It is possible to write a definitve answer for that at least. You are also right, of course, I should frame my question more restrictive, I just don't know how to do it. I could sample a large list of compilers and ask if those run the testcode (it's not production code, just written for the convenience of the readers here) succesfully. But that is also not a very good method, it's even worse, I would have to ask a separate question for every compiler(-version). Any suggestions?

Comment: The question about MSVC is good, I agree, but it doesn't rescue the rest.  It could be posed on its own in two or three sentences.  What you're after seems to be more of a discussion / multiple answer sort of thing, and that's just not the SO model.  I mean, SO certainly affords multiple answers to questions, but it's built around the concept that one of them can be the best.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So it's the list? Do I really have to ask dozens of individual single questions about some dozens compilers and their respective versions in about the same numerical range? Is there really nothing in between?

Comment: Some compilers for PIC processors used IEEE-like `float` where the infinity/NAN exponent was simply a finite number 2x the usual max finite exponent.  IOWs no support for `inf/NAN`.  Also same FP standard did not use sub-normals as usual.  all sub-normals were 0.0.

Comment: I suppose you're expecting an answer for antediluvian Cs, since `math.h` has included INFINITY and NAN since C99, and you can `#include <math.h>` to get the macros without linking libmath.

Comment: @rici yes, that would be nice, but see e.g.: the comment of chux (Thanks, chux!) to get the reason for some of my headaches. And these are definitely not antediluvian compilers. I wish they were.

Comment: If NAN is not defined by math.h, you can assume there is no NAN; it is not guaranteed to exist. But a simple ifdef should tell you. Afk atm but iirc INFINITY is allowed to be MAX_FLOAT. The standard is somewhat open; the question is whether the compilers support it. 1999 was quite a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Likely for `nan != nan`, with "fast math" turned on, the compiler is simply bit-testing the operands instead of doing the proper floating-point tests.

A NaN should never equal a NaN, because if the operands are not numbers, how the hell are we supposed to determine their equivalence *numerically*? Therefore, one should never attempt to determine a value's NaN-ness using `=`. One needs a special function to do that, probably involving looking at bits, or letting the FPU look at bits internally.

The way to detect cheating, as your code suggests, is to do a controlled test.

Comment: The OP seems to have a decent grasp of the numerical and representational issues you describe.  His question is not about them themselves, it is about how various C compilers / runtimes actually handle them in practice.